# Вебвизор Яндекс.Метрики не показывает переходы по ссылкам с Turbolinks

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails, yandex-metrika-api

Вебвизор записывает сеансы, видно перемещение мыши, нажатия на клавиши, скроллинг, щелчки по ссылкам. Но при переходе по ссылкам - страница не обновляется. В чем может быть проблема?

Использую [Turbolinks 5.0.1](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks). Сайт: [gambala.pro](http://www.gambala.pro/)

Счетчик метрики подключен с ключом `trackHash:true` для отслеживание хеша в url. Пробовал размещать скрипт в `body`, и в `data-turbolinks-permanent`-блоке - вебвизор в обоих случаях при переходах по ссылкам не обновляет страницу.

Код счетчика:

```
<!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function (d, w, c) {
    (w[c] = w[c] || []).push(function() {
      try {
        w.yaCounter39463510 = new Ya.Metrika({
          id:39463510,
          clickmap:true,
          trackLinks:true,
          accurateTrackBounce:true,
          webvisor:true,
          trackHash:true,
          ut:"noindex"
        });
      } catch(e) { }
    });

    var n = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
      s = d.createElement("script"),
      f = function () { n.parentNode.insertBefore(s, n); };
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";

    if (w.opera == "[object Opera]") {
      d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", f, false);
    } else { f(); }
  })(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");
</script>
<noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/39463510?ut=noindex" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
<!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->
```

Answer (score 2):

У яндекса есть такая вещь 
https://yandex.ru/support/metrika/code/ajax-flash.xml

Попробуйте при перезагрузки содержимого страницы отправлять

```
yaCounterXXXXXX.hit('http://example.com#contacts', {title: 'Контакты', referer: 'http://example.com/#main'});
```

Comment: Добавлял. В этом случае вебвизор поступает так: сперва показывает визит со всеми кликами, но без переходов по страницам (как было изначально в моем вопросе), а потом показывает подряд все аяксовые переходы по страницам, получается слайд-шоу из всех переходов в визите